# Sweep & prune broadphase algorithm

Tags: c#, game, opengl

My game engine uses the following broadphase collision detection algorithm:

```
internal void SweepAndPrune()
{
    // First: order all objects from left to right on the x-axis:
    IOrderedEnumerable<GameObject> axisList = _gameObjects.OrderBy(x => x.LeftRightMost.X);

    // loop through all objects:
    for(int i = 0; i < axisList.Count(); i++)
    {
        // For each object, iterate over all the subsequent objects in the list
        // and find out if there are overlaps on the x-axis:
        for(int j = i+1; j < axisList.Count(); j++)
        {
            GameObject a = axisList.ElementAt(i);
            GameObject b = axisList.ElementAt(j);
            if(b.Left > a.Right)
            {
                // if their is no overlap, then the rest will not overlap as well.
                // might as well stop the inner loop here:
                break;
            }
            // if there is an overlap, add A to B's list 
            // and B to A's list of potential collisions.
            // [every object's list of collision candidates is 
            // cleared before the next frame]
            a._collisionCandidates.Add(b);
            b._collisionCandidates.Add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, this algorithm slows down the performance by a lot if there are > 50 objects on screen.
Also, the list of GameObject instances (_gameObjects) needs to get sorted another time per frame because I need to order the objects by their distances from the camera (background objects need to get rendered first because of transparency!).

Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Comment: for starter, you could convert `axisList` to list or array, and  use `.Count` or `.Length` instead of `Count()` , then replace `ELementAt` with regular index `axisList[i]`. This would give you some performance boost, the rest would be outside the loop scope I guess.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` (and `IOrderedEnumerable`) represents a *question*, not an answer. `axisList` is not really a list -- it is a *question* asking "What is the sequence of elements from `_gameObjects` ordered by X value?". So every time you do this:

```csharp
            GameObject a = axisList.ElementAt(i);
            GameObject b = axisList.ElementAt(j);
```

You are *answering* the question "What is the `i`th element in that ordering". Which means it needs to re-order the sequence on every iteration! Your outer loop ends up being hugely expensive (O(n^3 log(n)) if my math checks out); you certainly don't need to do that.

You should cache the result of the ordering and re-use it in your loop. Change this

```csharp
IOrderedEnumerable<GameObject> axisList = _gameObjects.OrderBy(x => x.LeftRightMost.X);
```

to this:

```csharp
var orderedByX = _gameObjects.OrderBy(x => x.LeftRightMost.X).ToList();
```

`.ToList()` will evaluate the `OrderBy` query and return a flattened "answer" that you can keep reusing, and as a bonus it has O(1) lookup so `ElementAt` is fast -- you could even change `ElementAt(i)` to `[i]` to make that more clear.

Comment: Holy moly! My game loop just went from 16.4ms to 1.9ms with 100 objects on screen. In debug mode! This is the biggest performance increase I have ever seen. I feel so stupid! Thank you both Jeff and iSR5 for helping me. Special thanks to Jeff for elaborating. Wow! I am stunned!!!

Comment: And if `_gameObjects` doesn't change often relative to how often your algorithm runs, you could even just re-sort it every time it changes rather than every time you run your algorithm. Or use a `SortedList` for `_gameObjects` which does that for you automatically.

Comment: I am very grateful for your enthusiasm! I will try that as well. Hell, I wish there was something that I could help YOU with - but you seem to be a lot more experienced than I am :-(